# Conflict between logging module, Latex and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, logging, latex

The following example:

```
import logging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

mpl.rc('font', family='serif', serif="DejaVu Serif")
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)

# Set up logging module
level = logging.INFO
frmt = '%(message)s'
handlers = [
    logging.FileHandler("test.log", mode='a'),
    logging.StreamHandler()]
logging.basicConfig(level=level, format=frmt, handlers=handlers)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(.5, .5)
plt.xlabel("test label")
plt.savefig("del.png")
```

generates dozens of warnings:

```
No LaTeX-compatible font found for the serif fontfamily in rcParams. Using default.
```

All these go away and the output stays apparently exactly the same if I comment out the `serif="DejaVu Serif"` argument. I can also leave that argument in and comment out the `logging` block, and the warnings also go away.

I'm running elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 22.04.3) with apparently all the required fonts  and LaTeX packages installed.

Is this a conflict between the `logging` module and my system's fonts? Is this an issue with `logging` and LaTeX? What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handlers you've configured don't use fonts *per se* - they just output text messages. My guess is that `matplotlib` or some other library is logging messages (called from your code after the `basicConfig()` call), but they don't show up unless you configure logging. This could explain why the messages either go away if you remove logging (messages are generated, but don't appear because there's no logging handlers to output them), or if you remove the `serif=` argument (events aren't logged in that case).

I advise you to leave both in and change the format string `frmt` to include `%(name)s` and `%(levelname)s` in order to see where the messages are being logged, and at what severity. That should give a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Inclusing `%(name)s` and `%(levelname)s` the message is : `matplotlib.texmanager INFO No LaTeX-compatible font found...` so apparently it is indeed a message from `matplotlib` that is hidden unless I activate the logger. Thank you!